# Encode arbitrary string to JSON in http response

Tags: json, go, negroni

I have a string of JSON that I want to encode as json into an http response.

This returns a string in the response:

```
str := "{\"key1\":{\"key2\":\"value1\",\"key3\":\"value2\"}}"
err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(str)
```

I'm trying to first marshal the string to JSON. Which gives me another string of random bytes.

```
str := "{\"key1\":{\"key2\":\"value1\",\"key3\":\"value2\"}}"
js, _ := json.Marshal(str)
err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(js)
```

Comment: If `str` is already json, why are you trying to marshal it? (you're also trying to re-marshal it twice)

Comment: You already have json, you don't need to encode it as json, just use it

Comment: so the first example I have should work?

Comment: or use `w.Write()` ?

Comment: yes, just write the json to your `ResponseWriter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution (w is the responseWriter)

```
str := "{\"key1\":{\"key2\":\"value1\",\"key3\":\"value2\"}}"
w.Write([]byte(str))
```

Comment: Instead of all those `\"`, use `\`raw strings\``.

Comment: this is bad security practice, your languages default encoding and decoding json methods should always be used.